# MockMvcRequestBuilders.asyncDispatch providing an empty HTTP Response and contentType

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-test, spring-test-mvc

I have a unit test, where i am attempting to check the response of a async request being made, after converting the method to return a *StreamingResponseBody* using Spring 4.3.

The test method is below :

```
final MockMvc mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac)
     .apply(SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity())
     .build();

MvcResult mvcResult1 = mockMvc.perform(
   get("/reports/generic/100?FIELD1=&FIELD3=").headers(STANDARD_HEADERS.get()))
  .andExpect(status().isOk())
  .andExpect(request().asyncStarted())
  .andReturn();

mvcResult1.getAsyncResult();

mockMvc.perform(asyncDispatch(mvcResult1))
                    .andExpect(status().isOk())
                    .andExpect(content().contentType("text/csv"))
                    .andExpect(content().string("Test Data" + System.lineSeparator() + "FIELD1=" + System.lineSeparator() + "FIELD3=" + System.lineSeparator()))
```

The method it is calling looks like :

```
public StreamingResponseBody streamReport(@PathVariable("type") @NotNull String type, @PathVariable("id") @NotNull Long id, ReportConfiguration config, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {


    ReportServiceHandler handler = reportHandlerFactory.getHandler(type);
    final String reportFilename = handler.getReportFileName(id, reportConfiguration);

    response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment;filename=" + reportFilename);
    response.setContentType("text/csv");

    return new StreamingResponseBody() {

        @Override
        public void writeTo(OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {

            try {
                response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment;filename=" + reportFilename);
                response.setContentType("text/csv");
                ServletOutputStream out = (ServletOutputStream) outputStream;
                handler.generateReport(out, id, reportConfiguration);
                out.flush();
            } catch ( Exception e ) {
                response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "inline");
                response.setContentType("");
                throw new IOException(e);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Debugging shows that the original request has the response from the async within it, but the async response object (within *mvcResult1*) is **not** being copied over during *asyncDispatch* so both the contextType and content string is null.

Is there a test configuration being missed here that handles async mvcResult so that the content can be asserted ?

Answer (score 0):

I have been quite successful with this. Here is what I do differently:

```
    return new StreamingResponseBody() {

    @Override
    public void writeTo(OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {

        try {
            ... same
            out.flush();
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            ... your error handling
        } finally {
            // Try to close the stream
            try {
                if (out != null) {
                    out.close();
                }
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                // not much we can do
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Now, my tests look as such when made parallel to yours. When reading your code, I'm not sure why you call perform() twice. To me it's necessary only once.

```
//Same
final MockMvc mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac)
   .apply(SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity())
   .build();

// Same
MvcResult mvcResult1 = mockMvc.perform(
get(....))
  .andExpect(status().isOk())
  .andExpect(request().asyncStarted())
  .andReturn();
    
mvcResult1.getAsyncResult();

// From this point on, I have complete response,
// if it's not bugging you to place the entire file in memory
String thisIsYourFileContent = mvcResult1.getResponse().getContentAsString();

// Go on asserting the content of the file...
```

In the hope this helps someone.